# Who tips Hank off about his imminent assassination by The Cousins?

Tags: breaking-bad

In the episode "One Minute" of Breaking Bad, Hank gets a phone call from a digitally modified voice, telling him that he would be killed in a minute's time. Who initiated this phone call?

Some sources say [Victor made the call](https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/yjgh1/hey_whats_up_guys_this_is_jeremiah_bitsui_aka/c5w7w07) (claimed by the actor himself) and others [claim Gus](https://www.quora.com/Who-tipped-Hank-off-before-he-was-attacked-in-Breaking-Bad-season-3). Was this ever explicitly mentioned on the show itself? If it was, what is the definitive answer?

Answer (score 4):

Fairly sure it was mentioned on the show, but also according to AMC's [character page for Gus](http://www.amc.com/shows/breaking-bad/cast-crew/gustavo-fring), he's the one who tipped off Hank.

> Meanwhile, two Cartel killers, the Cousins, travel from Mexico to murder Walt to avenge the death of Tuco, his previous distributor. Gus instead steers them toward DEA Agent Hank Schrader but also tips off Hank about the attack.

Comment: Fine, but how did Gus know when the cousins were one minute away? My guess is that he had Mike following them.

Answer (score 0):

Gus was the one who warned Hank about the attack. It was also mentioned here, under the trivia section...
http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/One_Minute